# C# JWT Accessing Token in Method

Tags: c#, jwt

I'm trying to access an existing JWT within a method call. For example, I have the following method and I'd like to access the JWT that came in with the request. I could access the Authorize header and recreate the token but I imagine there's a more elegant solution than that.

.MapGet("/Validate", [Authorize] (HttpRequest httpRequest) =>...

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to access the token itself?

Comment: I need to validate the client making the call and want to log some information tied to data stored in the JWT.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an existing JWT from the `HttpContext.Request` property.

From your question it seems you are using minimal API, you can try the code below:

```cs
app.MapGet("/Validate", context => context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Request.Headers["authorization"]));
```

`context.Request.Headers["header-name"]` is the code you access a single header.

*Please be mindful that HttpContext is not thread safe, [as documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0)*

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was something native that would take care of pulling out the header value, removing the "bearer " text and creating a JWT natively. It would seem that the JWT is created based on the header if nothing else to verify the validity of the token to make sure it hasn't been tampered and to verify any role information to make sure the user is able to make the call to the method.